# Sporadic SVN checkout failure

Tags: svn, version-control

I am experencing ramdon checkout failures with a repository that I just created using filtered dumps from another repo. I am accessing it via Apache WebDAV.

Roughly speaking, there is a 25% chance that a fresh checkout can fail, with either of the two error messages:

```
svn: E160004: Corrupt representation '128 9 111 98 2fdc6c36a75b97744d20c04eecb701c3'

svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML
svn: E130003: Malformed XML: no element found
```

This behavior occurs on both of my two computers at distinct physical locations. It also occurs on the same machine that hosts the Apache server.

I tried to verify the repository on the server side with `svnadmin verify`. It did not report any problem.

How I can debug and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is gone after restarting `httpd`. Apparent it is a bad idea to hot-update the repository using the svn command-line tools. I suspect this might have caused some consistency issue with the Apache server.